# Cucumber support not working within Aptana Studio 3.3.2

Tags: cucumber, aptana

I have recently started working with Cucumber in my Rails project and I have noticed 2 things that are bot working as I would expect within Aptana Studio.

1. There seems to be no editor support for a .feature file to provide syntax colorization. When I go to Preferences->General->File Associations I can create an association for .feature but there is no internal editor for Cucumber to associate itr with.
2. All of the commands are disabled under Commands->Cucumber such as Feature/Scenario etc.

The cucumber ruble is installed in the same folder as the other rubles which are working (ruby, sass etc). Is there an install or config enable or something I have to do to activate Cucumber within my Rails project.

Note that cucumber-rails is an installed gem in the Gemfile of my project.

So, in summary...
1) How do I get the editor to recognise Cucumber syntax
2) What do I need to do to use the Cucumber commands from within Aptana Studio?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Associate it (by default) with Text Editor (Studio) and commands are enabled.

Please reply if that works for you.

Regards
Andre.

Comment: Hi Andre. 

Thanks. That works enough to enable the Commands menu although I was hoping that there would be some intelligence and colorisation in the syntax that came with that which doesnt appear to be the case?

Also, there are still some unavailable commands (Given Step, When Step, Then Step, Cucumber Multiline Steps).

Cheers